# Check the proof by Cauchy's: existence of a function satisfying $ f ( x ) + f ( 2 x ) + \dots + f ( n x ) = 0 $, and $ f ( x ) = 0 $ iff $ x = 0 $

Tags: functions, solution-verification, functional-equations

> Let $ n \ge 2 $ be an integer. Show that there exists a function $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ such that
> $$ f ( x ) + f ( 2 x ) + \dots + f ( n x ) = 0 $$
> for all $ x \in \mathbb R $, and $ f ( x ) = 0 $ if and only if $ x = 0 $.

**Attemp:**

Let's consider Cauchy's functional equation:
$$ f ( 0 + 0 ) = f ( 0 ) + f ( 0 ) \implies f (0) = 0 \text . $$
$$ f ( 2 x ) = f ( x + x ) = f ( x ) + f ( x ) = 2 f ( x ) \text . $$
By induction it follows that $ f ( n x ) = n f ( x ) $.
Let's get to the problem:
$$ f ( x + 2 x + \dots + n x ) = f ( x ) + f ( 2 x ) + \dots + f ( n x ) = \\
= f ( x ) + 2 f ( x ) + \dots + n f ( x ) = ( 1 + 2 + \dots + n ) f ( x ) = 0 \text . $$
So $ f ( x ) = 0 \implies x = 0 $. So there is a function that satisfies the given conditions.

Am I right?

Comment: What tells you that $f$ satisfies Cauchy's functional equation?

Comment: To answer the question: no, this is incorrect.

Comment: @jMdA Why, jmda?

Comment: @LockyPauk There's no reason you can apply linearity of $f$, and you never exclude the possibility that $f$ is identically $0$ for every value of $x$. This assertion doesn't follow from the equation $f(x)(1+2+\ldots+n) = 0$ or any other equation in that last line. You also never construct this function, or prove it exists. You assume some properties of a hypothetical function $f$ and prove some properties of this hypothetical function. This doesn't answer the question.
When proving a statement like "there exists..." the easiest is to construct an explicit example.

Comment: You haven't shown that your $f$ satsifies $f(x)+f(2x)+\ldots=0$ for each $x$